# Travelling from Saudi Arabia to Toronto on dual passports, visa waiver with American?

Tags: canada, us-citizens, dual-nationality, saudi-arabia, pakistani-citizens

I am little confused this time because my son has dual passports (Pakistani and American), now we are going to Toronto, Canada and for US nationals a visa is not required.

But in this case, we are using his Pakistani passports on iqama (permanent resident card) so his exit will be on Pakistani passport. Is it ok for him to travel out using the Pakistani passport and then show his US passport in Canada for a visa exemption?

Comment: Can you clarify, you've said Saudi Arabia in the title and tag, but say he's Pakistani? Which is it?

Comment: Specifically, you said flying out of a Pakistani passport - did you mean airport, or did you mean Pakistani passport from Saudi Arabia?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dual nationality, not sure how to switch passports!](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34714/dual-nationality-not-sure-how-to-switch-passports)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to show visa documentation to board the flight to Canada.  Assuming the rest of your family is traveling on your Pakistani passports and if your Iqama status is noted in those passports, the airline may wish to see his Pakistani passport as well at check-in to make sure he is documented to leave. But they should accept his US passport as proof of permission to enter Canada.

The question would be if Saudi Arabia requires proof of travel upon your return.  This happened to us in Africa, as my daughter used her second passport to avoid visa issues, but then was hassled since her exit visa from the previously visited country was not in the passport she presented to enter the next country.